# Why am I encountering major lag in Q.U.B.E?

Tags: technical-issues, qube

In Q.U.B.E (steam game), I can make it all the way up to the first few laser puzzles with no issues, but then my FPS will suddenly drop to 10-20.

My PC specs are as follows:

- AMD Phenom II 3.4Ghz Quad
- Sapphire Radeon HD 6870
- 8GB G.Skill DDR3
- 1TB Seagate Barracuda

I will normally get 60+ FPS up until said point.

This is a major issue for me as I am trying to record a let's play of the game, and I cannot progress if my FPS is so horrible!

**Note:** The FPS is horrible even if I'm not recording.

Comment: The game is running off of the unreal engine.  Last I heard, it doesn't run as great on ATI cards.

Comment: @JeffMercado As I said, I normally get 60+ FPS when playing. Also, AMD replaced ATI's graphics cards several years ago.

Comment: ATI/AMD, you know what I mean.  ;)

Comment: Is the FPS still so bad when you're not recording?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yes, it doesn't matter if I'm recording or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured out the cause of this.

As I am recording with Fraps, and Fraps uses the HDD relentlessly, my disk was rapidly becoming fragmented as I recorded.

Whenever I encounter this issue again, running a quick defrag fixes it right up!